# Throw error when creating react component conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component called ListChats and another called Chat.

ListChats calls the rendering of a Chat

I need that if an error occurs when rendering the Chat, ListChats knows and comes back with the list of available chats.

A possible error, its capture has not yet been implemented, would be if the user has no name, Chat captures this error and returns to ListChat.

**ListChats component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Chat from "../Chat";
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default class ListChats extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chat: <div />
    }
    this.toSala = this.toSala.bind(this);
  }
  
  toSala() {
    //this is where I render a Chat component, I need that, if it returns an error, I set this.state.chat to "<div />" 
    this.setState({chat: <Chat/>  });
  }
  render() {
    const { chat} = this.state;
    
    return (
      <>
         <Button  onClick={this.toSala}>abrir chat</Button>
         {chat} 
      </>
    )
  }

};
```

**Chat component**

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Chat = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {    
 //depending on the value of a variable of mine I have the need or not to throw an error when rendering this component 
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      my chat
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

In short, I need to throw an error in the Chat component and catch it in ListChats component

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: thanks for the link, but in the example it captures the error and returns: <h1> Something went wrong. </h1>, I need ListChat to know that an error has occurred and not for Chat to display the error that occurred

Comment: so return null then it will render empty element. You can pass info to parent component by context or some props.

Comment: thanks, I think maybe that will help me but I still need to think more

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in two ways:

first you can pass props from the parent to the child and communicate between the two components by this.set your variable in the parent component and pass that via props to the child component.in this case your child component is responsible to show whatever comes from the parent.

the second one is using a global state management like Redux,ContextApi or mobX to catch error in the child and save it to an state and then use that state in the parent component or wherever you want to use.

depend on the size of your project you can use either way.

Comment: I'll look at the second option, I believe that the first will not work because I need to pass the information from the son to the father, but thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the responses and comments I managed to elaborate the following solution:

1- I created a function in ListChat that will receive the error message (msg) by parameter:

```
setError = (msg) => {
    this.setState({error:msg});
   }
```

2- I passed the function as props in rendering the chat:

```
this.setState({chat: <Chat setError={this.setError}/>  });
```

3- When I need to now pass an error by the Chat for ListChat,
I call in the Chat component:

```
props.setError("Name is null");
```